# JSON & Javascript - Dynamic DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm learning JSON, and DOM Manipulation.  I've been trying to get my HTML code to dynamically update w/ information from a JSON file.

```
<div class="towns">
        <div class="franklin">
            <h3 class="town-title">Franklin</h3>
            <p class="f-motto">ssd</p>
            <p class="f-year">1232</p>
            <p class="f-pop">123123123</p>
            <p class="f-rain">1213</p>
        </div>
        <div class="greenville">
            <h3 class="town-title">Greenville</h3>
            <p class="g-motto">ssd</p>
            <p class="g-year">1232</p>
            <p class="g-pop">123123123</p>
            <p class="g-rain">1213</p>
        </div>
        <div class="springfield">
            <h3 class="town-title">Springfield</h3>
            <p class="s-motto">ssd</p>
            <p class="s-year">1232</p>
            <p class="s-pop">123123123</p>
            <p class="s-rain">1213</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the Javascript i'm using to retrieve data and also update the DOM.

```
<script>

    var requestURL = 'https://byui-cit230.github.io/weather/data/towndata.json';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', requestURL);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();

    request.onload = function() {
        var stats = request.response;
        populateHeader(stats);
        showHeroes(stats);
    }

     function populateHeader (jsonOBJ) {

            var motto = jsonOBJ['towns'][0]['motto'];
            document.querySelector('.f-motto').innerHTML = motto;
        }


</script>
```

As of right now I know i could statically update the 'motto' by putting in a number in jsonOBJ['towns'][number]; but, I was wanting to do something like this:

```
var n = 0;

var motto = jsonOBJ['towns'][n]['motto'];
```

and set all classes to .motto instead of .__-motto

i've tried doing a for loop to dynamically change variable 'n'; but, i've only gotten the same motto across all three elements. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

json code:

```
{
  "towns" : [
  {
    "name": "Franklin",
    "motto": "Where you will grow!",
    "yearFounded": 1788,
    "currentPopulation": 30458,
    "averageRainfall": 21,
    "events" : [
      "March 4: March to the Drum of Donuts",
      "September 5 - 11: Founder Days",
      "December 1 - 26: Christmas in the Heart"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Greenville",
    "motto": "Green is our way of life.",
    "yearFounded": 1805,
    "currentPopulation": 33458,
    "averageRainfall": 25,
    "events" : [
      "February 10-12: Greenbration",
      "May 8 - 18: Greenville Founder Days",
      "June 20: Verde and Valiant Day",
      "November 15-16: Greensome Gathering"
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "Placerton",
    "motto": "Positive Placement in Placerton.",
    "yearFounded": 1946,
    "currentPopulation": 512,
    "averageRainfall": 39,
    "events" : [
      "July 4: A Blaze of Glory",
      "October 20: Fall through Fall"
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "Springfield",
    "motto": "Where everyone is lifted.",
    "yearFounded": 1826,
    "currentPopulation": 17852,
    "averageRainfall": 17,
    "events" : [
      "January 8: Spring into Winter",
      "April 10-20: Celebration of Life",
      "July 31-Aug 15: Dog Days of Summer Festival"
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Please add part of the JSON to the question.  (I cannot access it, and it should be part of the question anyway to preserve your questions long-term value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a forEach to get your `n`.

```
//use querySelectorAll to get all the html elements in one go
var mottos = document.querySelectorAll('.f-motto');

//forEach passes in each element and it's index for each iteration
jsonOBJ['towns'].forEach(function(town, index){
    mottos[index].innerHTML = town.motto;
});
```

Comment: Actually for this to work, you will need to change the classes on your elements.  Other than the town-title, all the other classes are unique by row.  That makes this issue much harder than it needs to be.  Ideally you'd want similar elements to share a common class.